# Regex: possibly two patterns found in one text

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a specific pattern but the text to be processed can change randomly.
The text I am trying to filter currently using regex (Python.re.findall, python v3.9.13) is as follow:
`"ABC9,10.11A5:6,7:8.10BC1"`

I am using the following regex expression: `r"([ABC]{1,})(([0-9]{1,}[,.:]{0,}){1,})"`

The current result is:
`[("ABC", "9,10.11", "11"), ("A", "5:6,7:8.10", "10"), ("BC", "1", "1")]`

What I am looking for as result should be:
`[("ABC", "9,10.11"), ("A", "5:6,7:8.10"), ("BC", "1")]`

I don't understand why the last number in the second part is always repeated again.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you are using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), since that returns the contents of *all* capture groups in its output. In your case the last number repetition is due to the capture group around `[0-9]{1,}[,.:]{0,}`. Making that a non-capturing group resolves the issue:

```
([ABC]{1,})((?:[0-9]{1,}[,.:]{0,}){1,})
```

In python:

```py
re.findall(r"([ABC]{1,})((?:[0-9]{1,}[,.:]{0,}){1,})", s)
# [('ABC', '9,10.11'), ('A', '5:6,7:8.10'), ('BC', '1')]
```

Comment: Fast reply. Efficient and working perfectly. Thank you.